# How to reduce static query code duplication Gatsby JS

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I've created a React static query hook that requests site and page level meta data. At the moment I'm duplicating this code on every page build as 1 part of the query changes from page to page `allProductsJson`, `allProductJson` etc etc. I was wondering if it is possible to remove this duplication by using the querying capabilities more efficiently? I've read that Gatsby static queries don't support arguments, but maybe there's a way to query all meta and filter by page?

Example of a duplicated query hook:

```
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby';
import pageMetadataSelector from 'utils/page-metadata-selector';
import siteMetadataSelector from 'utils/site-metadata-selector';
import getAbsoluteUrl from 'utils/get-absolute-url-path';

const QUERY = graphql`
  {
    pageMetadata: allProductsJson {
      nodes {
        metadata {
          title
          description
          image {
            publicURL
          }
          robots
        }
      }
    }
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        siteUrl
      }
    }
  }
`;

const usePageMetadataQuery = ({ location }) => {
  const { pageMetadata, site } = useStaticQuery(QUERY);
  const pageData = pageMetadataSelector(pageMetadata);
  const { siteUrl } = siteMetadataSelector(site);

  return {
    metadata: {
      ...pageData,
      siteUrl: getAbsoluteUrl(siteUrl, location.pathname),
      image: getAbsoluteUrl(siteUrl, pageData.image.publicURL)
    }
  };
};

export default usePageMetadataQuery;
```

Comment: prepare external gql files, import (gql loader), choose/select by parameter

Comment: Could you explain this with an example @xadm

Comment: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#importing-graphql-files ... gatsby specific https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-graphql-loader/ .. but you need it at build time

Comment: @xadm I want to do the query at build time, it doesn't look like this plugin supports that:

> This is not for:
Loading queries used at build time.

Comment: yes, I wrote that ... 1st link rather for info or manual config... and more proper plugin for use https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-graphql-tag-loader/

Answer (score 1):

Given what you’re doing here, I think you would be better served by adding the relevant data to the page context in `gatsby-node.js` (in the `createPage` call), then using `wrapRootElement` (in `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js`) to extract those details from the page context.

From there you can either render the component you need directly or pass it to a React Context Provider for consumption by any children.

Here’s an example showing the latter:

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props: { context: { metadata} } }) => {
  return (
    <MetadataContext.Provider value={metadata}>
      {element}
    </MetadataContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

It’s also possible to fetch this data in each of your page queries and access it in the same way (destructure `data` instead of `context`):

```js
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const {
    data: {
      pageMetadata,
      pageData,
    }
  } = await graphql(`
    {
      pageMetadata: allProductsJson {
        nodes {
          slug
          metadata {
            title
            description
            image {
              publicURL
            }
            robots
          }
        }
      }

      pageData: allPageJson {
        pages: {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `

  // for each page
  pageData.pages.map(({ slug }) => {
    // select the metadata with the matching slug
    const { metadata } = pageMetadata.nodes.find(node => node.slug === slug)
    
    // create the page
    actions.createPage({
      path: `/${slug}/`,
      component: `./src/templates/page.jsx`,
      context: { 
        // pass both the slug and metadata as context
        slug,
        metadata,
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: question is about using slightly different queries always aliased to `pageMetadata` and processed the same way

Comment: @coreyward the metadata will change from page to page so I could be querying `allProductsJson` and then `allProductJson` etc, wondering how I could get this flexibility?

Comment: Right. Rather than plucking the data you need from `allProductJson` in the page query or a static query you just do it in `gatsby-node.js` and pass the relevant slice of it as context to the `createPage` call.

Comment: Otherwise you can use page queries, which are run for each page, to fetch this data. Also, you can still grab the `location` from the `props` prop passed to `wrapPageElement`, destructuring it just like I do `context` in the example above.

Comment: @coreyward apologies for coming back to this really late, the part I'm still not sure about is if I add the query to gatsby-node how can I pluck `allProductJson` then possibly `allStoresJson` and return that slice as context?

Comment: The fields like `allProductJson` or `productJson` are fields on the root `Query` object that happen to return the `ProductJson` type. You can query for multiple fields, so you can grab both `allProductJson` and `allStoresJson` at the same time. Then when you call `createPage` in `gatsby-node.js` you pass whatever pieces from the response data as part of the `context`. I'll add an example.

Comment: Really interesting @coreyward, and new Gatsby knowledge for me! I'm wondering how I would build upon the page.jsx component to customise the page? Would this createPage function be used more-so for pages that are the same design?

Comment: @styler Yes, that’s the idea. You’re creating pages based on data in GraphQL rather than hardcoded pages. If you aren’t using this then all you need to do is fetch filtered data in each page query and do away with the static query altogether.